# Is there a way to prevent multiple jsf bean creation?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

There is a code in jsf page (let's call it - page №1) that calls `myMethod()` method of `MyController` bean while loading:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="load" onsuccess="PF('pbAjax').start();myMethod();" autoRun="true"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="myMethod" async="true"
actionListener="#{MyController.myMethod(context)}" global="false"/>
```

That method **starts some task and "lives" until the end of that task (it has to be so)** which progress bar is seen on the page. While processing the task sometimes happens a swich to a page №2 if some condition is true. On page №2 user clicks continue button and goes back to page №1.

The problem is when user gets back to progress page (№1) **new instance of MyController is being created** and myMethod() is called again on this new instance. Eventually i get 8-10 bean objects (every with while loop) and app crashes.

I tried all types of annotations including `@ApplicationScoped` but nothing helps. So the question is **how to prevent creation of more than one bean?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just use session scoped and set a boolean if task has already started?

Comment: iI tried session scoped - same result. Boolean is ok, but a thought maybe there is some other, more correct way.

Comment: Bean scope determines how long bean instance must live, not how often a method may be invoked on the same instance. I guess you mixed both concepts.

Comment: I know. In my case bean doesn't die because it has method running regardless of scope type. But why jsf creates new instances all the time?

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that you know what you're talking about, then I can only tell that this is not the default behavior and that the cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far.